# How to enable/disable sections of a form based on required form elements having a value selected?

Tags: jquery

I have sections in a form that need to become enabled or disabled based on the previous section's required input values. All sections are disabled by default except the first one and inputs that are required have a class required applied. If the all required fields have a value then check the next section, if all those required fields have a value check the next section etc. After all required fields are enabled, say the user goes back and clears their first name, it should disable all of the next sections. Once the user types their first name again, check all of the next sections. Thanks! [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vG5u9/)

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="selStyled"><!--selStyled required for IE custom dropdowns-->
                    <select name="area" class="required">
                        <option value="">Pick something yo*</option>
                        <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
                        <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
                        <option value="option 3">option 3</option>
                        <option value="option 4">option 4</option>
                        <option value="option 5">option 5</option>
                        <option value="option 6">option 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name*" class="split-input required" />                  
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="split-input" />
            </div>

            <div class="section disabled">
                <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" disabled />
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City*" class="split-input required"  disabled />
                <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State/Province*" class="split-input required"  disabled />

            </div>

            <div class="section disabled">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Leave a comment sucka*" class="required" disabled ></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="submit" disabled />
        </form>
```

JS:

```
$('.contact-form input, .contact-form select, .contact-form textarea').bind('input propertychange change',function(){
    var currentInput = $(this);
    var currentContainer = currentInput.parent();
    var allRequired = 1;
    var requiredForm = 1;
    currentContainer.find('.required').each(function(){
        var currentRequiredValue = $(this).val();
        if(currentRequiredValue == '')
            allRequired = 0;
    });
    if(allRequired == 1) {//if not empty
        var nextSection = currentContainer.next('.section.disabled');
        nextSection.removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled').find('input, select, textarea').prop('disabled',false);


    }else{//if empty
        var enabledSections = currentContainer.nextAll('.section.enabled');
        enabledSections.removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled').find('input, select, textarea').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    $('.contact-form .required').each(function(){//check all required fields
        var formRequiredValue = $(this).val();
        if(formRequiredValue == '')
            requiredForm = 0;
    });
    if(requiredForm == 1){//send button
        $('.contact-form .submit').prop('disabled',false);
    }else{
        $('.contact-form .submit').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/vG5u9/1/

**JS Change:-**

<strike>var currentContainer = currentInput.parent();</strike>

```
var currentContainer = currentInput.closest(".section");
```

Comment: I still get the same issue. Say you make it all the way to the end of the form and then go back and clear a required input in the first section like the name. Then you type in your name again, the next section enables but the section after that stays disabled although the required inputs have values.

Comment: @PanchoVilla00 - Have tried with my JSFiddle? Becoz I m not seeing that issue.

Comment: Yes I tried yours. Fill out all required values until all sections are enabled (border green). Now in the first section set the first dropdown to "pick something yo", the rest go disabled (border red) which is what I want. Next on the same dropdown choose an option, notice how the second section is enabled (border green) but the third section is still disabled (border red). This section should also be enabled because the required fields in the second section have values.